# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/home/user/node_modules/angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

### The Problem

I got this error when running `ionic serve`

```
[ng] WARNING in /home/brian/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
[ng] 5659:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
[ng] WARNING in /home/brian/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
[ng] 5675:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
[ng] ERROR in /home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '/home/brian/node_modules/angularfire2'
[ng] ERROR in /home/brian/node_modules/rxjs-compat/_esm5/Observable.js
[ng] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/internal/Observable' in '/home/brian/node_modules/rxjs-compat/_esm5'
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

### Versions

I am using this version: 
**- Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit

- ionic 4.1.2 

- npm 6.4.1 

- node v8.12.0**

And here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "bin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "angular": "^1.7.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

### How to reproduce the issue

It is a very simple code, I just created a new ionic project `ionic start fleksales sidemenu`

Then under **app.module.ts**, I edited the code to be like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS } from './firebase.credentials';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
        // initialize AngularFire
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS)
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea how to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9",` only works with Angular 5. You'll probably have to upgrade to Angular 5+
Read the comment here:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1666#issuecomment-389709099

Comment: Hi @SiddAjmera thanks for your reply. I have upgraded the angularfire2 by running: `npm install firebase @angular/fire --save`. Now it is `"@angular/fire": "^5.0.2"` and `"firebase": "^5.5.1"`. However the error is still exactly the same.

Comment: I've also changed the `import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';` to `import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';` under **app.module.ts**. But still the error persists.

Comment: Please read my comment again carefully. Like I mentioned the issue is not with the version of AngularFire2. It's with the version of Angular. You're using Angular 4.4.6 but it requires Angular 5+

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @SiddAjmera. Sorry for asking such a simple question, but how to upgrade the Angular 4.4.6 to Angular 5+? I have ran `npm install -g @angular/cli` and it returns `+ @angular/cli@6.2.3`. But when I open the **package.json**, it is still `"@angular/core": "^4.4.6"`

Comment: Here's a user friendly guide to help you do just that:

https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180578/discussion-between-brian-ivander-t-p-and-siddajmera).